# Error installing lua-requests

Tags: lua, libstdc++, luarocks

I need to install the luarocks package `lua-requests`
But executing `sudo luarocks install lua-requests` returns this error:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/lua-requests-1.2-0.src.rock
Missing dependencies for lua-requests 1.2-0:
   xml (not installed)

lua-requests 1.2-0 depends on xml (not installed)
Installing https://luarocks.org/xml-1.1.3-1.src.rock

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/xml-1.1.3-1.src.rock - Could not find library file for STDC++
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/local/lib
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/local/lib64
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/local/lib
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/local/lib64
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/local/lib
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/local/lib64
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/lib
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.a in /usr/lib64
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/lib
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.so in /usr/lib64
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/lib
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /usr/lib64
  No file libstdc++.a in /lib
  No file libstdc++.a in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.a in /lib64
  No file libstdc++.so in /lib
  No file libstdc++.so in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libstdc++.so in /lib64
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /lib
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file matching libstdc++.so.* in /lib64
You may have to install STDC++ in your system and/or pass STDC++_DIR or STDC++_LIBDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install xml STDC++_DIR=/usr/local
```

But when executing `sudo luarocks install xml STDC++_DIR=/usr/local` I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid assignment: STDC++_DIR=/usr/local
```

**How can I install `lua-requests`?**

---

EDIT: Executing `sudo apt install libstdc++` returns this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64-cross' for regex 'libstdc+'
...
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-m68k-cross' for regex 'libstdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-arm64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-arm64-dcv1'
...
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-sparc64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-sparc64-dcv1'
libstdc++-5-dev is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10).
libstdc++-5-dev set to manually installed.
libstdc++6 is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
 libstdc++-4.9-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++-4.8-doc but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
 libstdc++-5-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++-4.8-doc but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++-4.9-doc but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12cross3 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12cross3 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12cross3 is to be installed
                                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2cross3 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-arm64-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
                                Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-armel-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12cross3 is to be installed
                                Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12cross3 is to be installed
                                Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
                                Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-powerpc-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2cross3 is to be installed
                                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64el-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross but 4.8.5-4ubuntu1cross2 is to be installed
                                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg-s390x-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-s390x-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note: *I had to remove some part of the APT output due to the chars limit*

Comment: do you have a file libstdc++.so in your system? if so, where? `locate libstdc++.so` can help you answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally "fixed" it by installing it on another machine without errors and copying all required files to that machine

Now everything works as it should

---

I know this shouldn't be done and it's not the proper way to do, but it's working now